# WebBrowser filling in values by name instead of ID

Tags: c#, browser, selenium-rc

I'm working on a form filling software, and I was wondering how would I go about selecting a field via name attribute or even CSS selector/XPath (like in selenium) via a web browser? Instead of `findbyid`?

Or Selenium RC is my only option?

Comment: Question is not very specific. Are you writing Selenium automated tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use XPath to select your elements.

Examples are on this page: http://wiki.openqa.org/display/SEL/Help+With+XPath

*Selenium supports many different locator types. Use the "xpath=" prefix for XPath locators, except where "xpath" is already in the method name.*

```
//form//input[@name="myFormFieldName"]
```

**EDIT**
To test on http://google.com

```
Command: type
Target: //form//input[@name="q"]
Value: TEST
```

After running this command, the input box on google.com should have the word TEST written on it.

Comment: I was trying to find a way to avoid using Selenium and just do it with WebBrowser

Comment: Sizzle and jQuery add selectors, but you're not going to be able to fill in a form without loading some JavaScript into the page, and unless it's your page, that ain't gonna work.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium isn't your *only* answer, but if you're trying to automate a web site, it's one of the *few* answers.  A web browser alone won't do the job.